# Error in CNN training

Tags: matlab, conv-neural-network

Please I need help on using CNN on image training. I am using the 'practical-cnn-2015a' demo.

Below is an excerpt of the codes as applied to my work, and the errors I encountered. Please help. Thank you

```
%% Load image dataset 

 imgFolder1 = fullfile('C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\practical-cnn-2015a\NairaNotes'); 

 trainingSet = imageSet(imgFolder1, 'recursive'); 

 %% 
 for digit = 1:numel(trainingSet)      

 numImages = trainingSet(digit).Count; 

     for i = 1:numImages img = read(trainingSet(digit), i); 

          im = rgb2gray(im2single(read(trainingSet(digit), i))); 
      end 

 labels = repmat(trainingSet(digit).Description, numImages, 1); 

   end 

 %% Visualize some of the data      

 figure(10) ; clf ; colormap gray ;   

 subplot(1,2,1) ; vl_imarraysc(img) ;  

 axis image off ; title('training chars for ''a''') ; subplot(1,2,2) ; 

 vl_imarraysc(img); axis image off ;  
 title('validation chars for ''a''') ; 

 %% ------------------------------------------------------------------------- % Part 4.2: initialize a CNN architecture % -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  net = initializeCharacterCNN() ; 

 %% % ------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 % Part 4.3: train and evaluate the CNN % ------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

 trainOpts.batchSize = 100 ;   
 trainOpts.numEpochs = 15 ;  
 trainOpts.continue = true ;  
 trainOpts.useGpu = false ; 
 trainOpts.learningRate = 0.001 ;  
 trainOpts.expDir = (img) ; 

  %% ----------------------------------------------------------
 %% i have errors in this section:  
 (attempt to execute SCRIPT varagin.m as a function)

  trainOpts = vl_argparse(trainOpts, varargin(:)); 

%% --------------------------------------------
%% Take the average image out 

 imdb = img ; 
 imageMean = mean(imdb(:)) ; 
 imdb = imdb - imageMean ; 

 %% Convert to a GPU array if needed 

   if trainOpts.useGpu 
      imdb = gpuArray(imdb) ; 
   end 

 %% pending: Call training function in MatConvNet 

 [net,info] = cnn_train(net, imdb, @getBatch, trainOpts) ;
```

> Error using fullfile (line 61) An unknown error occurred in FULLFILE while constructing the file specification.
>
> Error in cnn_train (line 92) modelFigPath = fullfile(opts.expDir, 'net-train.pdf') ;
>
> Error in trainCNN2 (line 72) [net,info] = cnn_train(net, imdb, @getBatch, trainOpts) ; Caused by:
>
> Error using horzcat Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Answer (score 1):

You've written

```
trainOps.expDir = (img);
```

which appears to be assigning an *image* to something that the code expects to be a *directory name*. So then it breaks when trying to construct a filename out of `expDir` and `'net-train.pdf'`.